# É possível usar a biblioteca stlport num Arduino, com cout?

Tags: arduino, biblioteca, io

Estou a trablahar num projeto com um Arduino no qual preciso de usar a biblioteca *Eigen*, por isso estou a usar [EigenArduino](https://github.com/vancegroup/EigenArduino). Contudo, esta biblioteca requer uma biblioteca standard, que não está disponível no Arduino, por *default*; por isso, como o *maintainer* do Eigen recomenda, tentei usar [stlport-avr](https://github.com/vancegroup/stlport-avr).

O problema é que, por default, esta biblioteca não disponibiliza acesso a *iostream*, logo não consigo usar *cout* para imprimir informação de *debug*. Já tentei usar o *Serial*, mas não funciona - o Eigen não foi feito para usar com isso.

Há alguma maneira de usar cout num Arduino. Ou pelo menos, uma maneira de usar Serial para imprimir informação de debug?